# Signal do not work in derived class

Tags: qt4, signals

I have such code:

```
class A : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) 
    {
        connect(&http, SIGNAL(done(bool)), this, SLOT(httpDone(bool)));    
    }

    void sendRequest() 
    {
        // ...
        http.request(...);
    }

public slots:
    void httpDone(bool)
    {
        qDebug() << "recieved!";
    }

protected:
    QHttp http;    

};

class B : public A
{
    //...
    void getSomething() 
    {
        sendRequest();
    }
};

class C : public A
{
    //...  
    void getSomething() 
    {
        sendRequest();
    }
};

// and now do some stuff
B b;
C c;
b.getSomething();
c.getSomething();
```

And there is only one "recieved!" message in console from b. Why?

Comment: what to `B` and `C`'s constructors look like?

Comment: You would need to post a complete example. Like this one can determine if you have a proper event loop.

Comment: Signals work  fine in derived classes - check the return code from connect() it tells you if you have made a mistake

Comment: Just little hint. QHttp is obsolete class. Use QNetworkAccessManager instead

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have Q_OBJECT macro in all the derived classes.